# Pass SASS variable to image URL

Tags: css, sass

I am using the following CSS code to generate a baseline background on my website during development:

```
html { 
    background-image: url(http://basehold.it/i/24/777777);
}
```

I would like to pass a SASS variable of `$base-line-height` into the URL, so it works like this:

```
html { 
    background-image: url(http://basehold.it/i/$base-line-height/777777);
}
```

But I keep getting an error when compiling. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: @cimmanon marking a question as duplicate without a link to the original question is the most non-constructive thing one can do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
html { 
    background-image: url(http://basehold.it/i/#{$base-line-height}/777777);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using single or double quotes:

```
html { 
    background-image: url('http://basehold.it/i/'+$base-line-height+'/777777');
}
```

Comment: Certainly the cleaner solution.